# Using sql column names in hibernate createSQlquery result

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc

I have a couple of sql views with composite primary keys that I want to query, and since Hibernate makes it a pain to work with composite keyes,  I'm using `createSQLQuery`. The problem is that this method can only return a List, and I need to refer to the colums by their index.

Any chance I could do something like jdbc and refer to the columns by their sql name instead of their index?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
Query query=session.createSQLQuery("your query");
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List<Map<String,Object>> aliasToValueMapList=query.list();
```

As you can figure out from code, the list contains Map objects representing each row. Each Map object will have column name as key and value as value.

Note: This work for SQLQuery, if your using AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer on hql query without specifying aliases you will get index value as key.

If you are again transforming aliasToValueMapList to your POJO  list, I advice you to create your own
[ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) and return your custom object from 'transformTuple' method.

Comment: btw, i have a sql query in the form "select table1.price as price1 from ..." and for some reason the AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer is not mapping price1. If i do "select (table1.price*1) as price1 from ..." it works though. So i think i found a bug in the transformer..

Comment: Remember to add `addScalar` declarations (e.g.  `query.addScalar("myAlias", IntegerType.INSTANCE)`). Otherwise you might get incorrect aliases (e.g. converted to upper-case) or incorrect data types.

Comment: Somehow I have to add this import to make it to work: 
import org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ambiguous - in the first paragraph you want to refer to columns by index and in the second, by sql name. Since by index is easy, I'll assume by name.

First of all, you can use the `doWork` method to access the underlying JDBC connection and handle it as you would with pure JDBC:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
  public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    connection.prepareStatement(...
  }
});
```

Or, you can use `query.getReturnAliases` which returns a `String[]` of the column names. For effciency, I'd probably build a `Map` of alias to index and then you can do something like `result[map.get("column name")]`.

But really, Hibernate handles composite keys pretty easily when using xml mappings (haven't tried with annotations). It's a little more work up front and there are a few issues with complex relationships (mainly when foreign key names/spans don't match), but once you create the id class and map it, you can stick with *HQL/Criteria* and get all the benefits of lazy loading, simple joins, dirty checking, etc.

Comment: @Brian, thanks! yes, i meant access by name, not index ;)
@Adi, yes, that's the answer i wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem but it solved when i used this

```
Query query=session.createSQLQuery("your query");
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

I get the result with header name but i got a new problem when i create a new column in sql query Select 'DCA5E3'  as Shipmentcolor from Employee.class
But in this case i got SHIPMENTCOLOR: "D".
How to get whole value of SHIPMENTCOLOR.