# Errors while iterate over a List of objects in hibernate +Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I need to iterate and manipulate the list with my corresponding getters and setters. I tried the following based on the forum answer [Retrieving Hibernate query result as result set instead of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296616/retrieving-hibernate-query-result-as-result-set-instead-of-list)
But it goes with the errors given below.Anyone can suggest what went wrong here?

```
Query query  = session.createSQLQuery("select s.id,e.firstName, e.middleName  from SecurityPrincipals as s " +
        "left join Employee as e on e.userId=s.id " +
        " where s.id= :userId").addEntity(EmployeeDTO.class);
query.setParameter("userId", userId);
List<EmployeeDTO> list = query.list();
Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); 
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{

    EmployeeDTO employeeDTO =  (EmployeeDTO) iterator.next();
    System.out.println("FirstName is:"+employeeDTO.getFirstName());
}
```

Following is my stacktrace.

```
Problem accessing /employeelist.jsf. Reason:

    org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.fetchinglife.temp.EmployeeDTO
Caused by:

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.fetchinglife.temp.EmployeeDTO
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:915)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.fetchinglife.temp.EmployeeDTO
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:548)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.getSQLLoadable(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processRootReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.process(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.<init>(SQLCustomQuery.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.<init>(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:150)
    at com.fetchinglife.temp.EmployeeView.viewEmployee(EmployeeView.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 64 more
```

Comment: have you created a hibernate mapping / annotated the entity for EmployeeDTO ?

Comment: @aishwarya: No actually EmployeeDTO is just a DTO class file..

Comment: cool, so it should not be added as an entity then :-) I guess axtavt's answer should help you then! You may need to add your entity (Employee?) though.

Comment: yea,now its working fine, thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `addEntity()` with classes that are not entities (for example, with DTOs). In this case you need to use [`AliasToBeanResultTransformer`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html) instead:

```
Query query  = session.createSQLQuery("select s.id,e.firstName, e.middleName  from SecurityPrincipals as s " +
        "left join Employee as e on e.userId=s.id " +
        " where s.id= :userId")
        .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(EmployeeDTO.class));
```

Note that aliases of selected properties should match properties of `EmployeeDTO`. If it's not so, you need to declare aliases for selected properties manually.