# How to retrieve data from object in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to join two table:
T1:id,name,email
T2:id,address

to join I am doing this:

```
String hql="select sd.name,tt.name from T1 sd,T2 tt where sd.id=tt.id";
            Query q=ss.createQuery(hql);
            List l2=q.list();
            Object o1=l2.get(0);
            System.out.println("-----------");
            System.out.println(o1.toString());
            System.out.println("-----------");
```

It is returning object but dont get how to retrieve the values as returned object is not entity object.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607337/hibernate-query-for-selecting-multiple-values

Comment: I'm certain there are better, more automated ways, to do this but as written it's a little difficult to gleam what you're actually asking.

Comment: @Rubio:Thanks man! It helps a lot

Comment: @Rake You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every result is an Object Array.The Array's size is the select columns

```
List l2=q.list();
Object[] o1=(Object[])l2.get(0);//The size is should be 2
System.out.println(o1[0]);
System.out.println(o1[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks ... it is like RubioRic's ans.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the `Object`'s in the `List` to your specific type, Hibernate does not know the type. See [What is the "proper" way to cast Hibernate Query.list() to List<Type>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913150/what-is-the-proper-way-to-cast-hibernate-query-list-to-listtype) and [Hibernate query for selecting multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607337/hibernate-query-for-selecting-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0):

it will return `array` of `Object` which you need to typecast as per your select values like name etc.

```
List<Object[]> values= (List<Object[]>)q.list();
     for(Object[] val: values){

....
//your specific type values
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... it is like RubioRic's ans

Answer (score 0):

Another option is creating a view with your joined tables, then, create hibernate entity base on that view