# java.lang.classcastexception while retrieving data from multiple tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to fetch different columns from different tables in hibernate.
My query is :

```
@NamedQuery(name="findAllfundSalesCreditCalc",query=" select distinct SF.subFundName, SF.id, case when FCM.subFundId is null "
                +" then 'Not yet added' else 'Already exists' end as ExistsOrNot,CCM.calculationMethodName," 
                +" FCM.effectiveFromDate, FCM.effectiveToDate,FCM.paymentFrequencyId,"
                +" FCM.firstPaymentDate from FundSalesCreditCalcMethod FCM ,SubFund SF , Class C ,"
                +" SC_Class SCC, SalesCreditCalcMethod CCM where SF.id = FCM.subFundId and "
                +" CCM.id = FCM.salesCreditCalcMethodId and "
                +" C.id = SF.id and "
                +" SCC.classId = C.id")
```

I am retrieving the data in a list.

```
List<FundSalesCreditCalcMethod> fundSalesCreditCalc = getFundSalesCreditCalcMethodDao().getFundSalesCreditCalc(); 

public List<FundSalesCreditCalcMethod> getFundSalesCreditCalc() {
        return this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("findAllfundSalesCreditCalc").getResultList();
    }

public List<FundSalesCreditCalcMethodDTO> getFundSalesCreditCalculation() {
/*      List<Object> fundSalesCreditCalc = getFundSalesCreditCalcMethodDao().getFundSalesCreditCalc();*/
        List<FundSalesCreditCalcMethod> fundSalesCreditCalc = getFundSalesCreditCalcMethodDao().getFundSalesCreditCalc();
        List<FundSalesCreditCalcMethodDTO> fundSalesCreditCalcMethodDtos = new ArrayList<FundSalesCreditCalcMethodDTO>();
        for(FundSalesCreditCalcMethod fundSalesCredit: fundSalesCreditCalc) {
            fundSalesCreditCalcMethodDtos.add(DTOCreator.createfundSalesCreditCalcDTO(fundSalesCredit));
        }
        return fundSalesCreditCalcMethodDtos;
    }
```

this is giving error :`java.lang.classcastexception`.

Comment: pls provide the code from getFundSalesCreditCalc method

Comment: You should really show us the full Java code where you are making the JPA call.

Comment: If you execute a query with Hibernate that return multiple values usually you get List<Object[]>. Maybe the ClassCastException is being thrown when you try to access the returned list.

Comment: I have added the whole code.Can you please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @shree Can you try with `createNamedQuery("findAllfundSalesCreditCalc", FundSalesCreditCalcMethod.class).getResultList()` instead of `createNamedQuery("findAllfundSalesCreditCalc").getResultList()`

Comment: I suspect that won't work, query is not returning FundSalesCreditCalcMethod objects.

Comment: @RubioRic You are right. My mistake, oversight.

Comment: @shree In this link you may find what your looking for and additional links for extended info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829197/how-to-return-object-type-instead-of-listobject-in-hibernate

Comment: @shree Another solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607337/hibernate-query-for-selecting-multiple-values