# How to use ResultSetMetaData in Spring-Hibernate Integration?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

In my JSP page I am displaying the employee detail in the DB and giving the table column name in the form of hard coded.now I need to know how to get the table column name dynamically ?

I aware of ResultSetMetaData to use it only in JSP. But I don't know how to get the column name when using the Spring-Hibernate Integration in JSP.

Please any one help to solve this?

My JSP page will be ,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="include.jsp" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="displayuser.html"  commandName="displayuser">  


<table width="100%" align="center">

 <tr style="background-color:#6B8E23  ;">
  <td align="center">Employee Id</td>
  <td align="center">Employee Name</td>
  <td align="center">Employee Password</td>
    <td align="center">Gender</td>
  <td align="center">Designation</td>
 </tr>

 <core:forEach items="${DisplayuserDetail}" var="userObj">
    <tr style="background-color:#9ACD32 ;">
       <td align="center"><core:out value="${userObj.empId}"/></td>
       <td align="center"><core:out value="${userObj.empName}"/></td>
       <td align="center"><core:out value="${userObj.empPassword}"/></td>
       <td align="center"><core:out value="${userObj.gender}"/></td>
       <td align="center"><core:out value="${userObj.designation}"/></td>
    </tr>
 </core:forEach>

</table>

</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance ... and your help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Hibernate persistent objects use annotations you could [read the annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296910/is-it-possible-to-read-the-value-of-a-annotation-in-java) off the domain objects.

Alternatively, see if the answers to [this question on getting SQL column names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2605385/217324) are helpful.