# how to get the table2 information using hibernate concept

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 tables in my database

- table1--> id, name, address
- table2--> id, tb1id

How can I get the table2 information using hibernate framework?

Comment: use `resultsetmetadata`

Comment: can you tell me the if we use Hibernate framework

Comment: [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html

Comment: The answer is not cleared

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `ResultsetMetaData` in spring/hibernate.

Check this answer..

[Use annotations for getting ResultsetMetaData.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14480990/2722799)

Thanks..

Comment: Can i use the Table per class Heirarchy rleation in Inheritance mapping concept in Hibernate  for getting table2 information