# Get dynamic SQL column names from Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have an Oracle table that has a CLOB in it. Inside this CLOB can be a SQL statement. This can be changed at any time.

I am currently trying to dynamically run these SQL statements and return the column names and data back. This is to be used to dynamically create a table on the web page.

Using Hibernate, I create the query and get the data like so:

```
List<Object[]> queryResults = null;
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery(sqlText);
queryResults = q.list();
```

This gets the data I need, but not the column names. I have tried using the `getReturnAliases()` method, but it throws an error that the "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: SQL queries do not currently support returning aliases"

So my question is: Is there a way through Hibernate to get these values dynamically?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605385/using-sql-column-names-in-hibernate-createsqlquery-result and see if it fills your need

Comment: Want to place your comment into an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use :

```
q.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List<Map<String,Object>> aliasToValueMapList=query.list();
```

to get column names in createSQLQuery.

For more details please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605385/using-sql-column-names-in-hibernate-createsqlquery-result) question.

Comment: If I just want the name without put in the map?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the addScalar method to define the columns.

Look at 16.1.1
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a ResultTransformer ( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html ) and set it on the native query. I think with a native SQL query you get the aliases as specified in the SQL as alias parameter in the callback method.

Answer (score 1):

In 2018 I would suggest using NativeQueryTupleTransformer with native queries.

```
query.setResultTransformer(new NativeQueryTupleTransformer());
```

The result format is `List<Tuple>`. This format is very convenient to work with native SQL queries.