# i want to get alias column name and value in java spring hibernate

Tags: spring

```
  String mainQuery = "select x as CONDITION_"+i+" from xyz";
  SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(mainQuery);
```

from this query i will get allias column like

```
  CONDITION_x
  ------------
  value_x(anything)
```

here x is int value it will increment 0,1,2...

From this i want Json like ,

```
 [ 
   { 
     "CONDITION_0" :"value",
     "CONDITION_1" :"value"
   }
 ]
```

And this is in spring hibernate.
Please help,TIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate auto increment field in select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555454/how-to-generate-auto-increment-field-in-select-query)

Comment: This should help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605385/using-sql-column-names-in-hibernate-createsqlquery-result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hibernate `ResultTransformer`'s which converts SQLQuery result to `Map<k,v>` object with the alias column name in query as the **k-key** and row value as **v-value**.

```
String mainQuery = "select x as CONDITION_"+i+" from xyz";
SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(mainQuery);
List<Map<String,Object>> result = sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list();
```

By this you can get the json result as you expected.